# trying to install pyperclip in python2.7

Tags: python, pip, installation, ubuntu-16.04, sudo

everytime i run this i face this problem

```
> sudo pip install pyperclip

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
        from pip import main
      File "/home/ot/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
      File "/home/ot/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip.compat import console_to_str, expanduser, stdlib_pkgs
ImportError: No module named compat
```

*ps: im using python 2.7 and this has been happening to me while trying to download other few packages as well*

I'm on **ubuntu 16.04**

Thank you

> **problem solved** i used these 2 lines :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pyperclip
```

Comment: Which os? On ubuntu 16.04 I have no issue.

Comment: `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @MegaIng I doubt `apt` could upgrade `pip` that resides in `/home/ot/.local/lib/python2.7/`.

Comment: half the time, problems like these get solved by upgrading pip itself